# sed - remove spaces between curly brackets

Tags: sed

I am writing a (terrible) CSS minifier and ran into some trouble when removing spaces.

I have the following to remove spaces generally but spaces matter in CSS. So to compensate I am trying to remove the spaces from between the curly braces only.

```
sed -i 's/ //g' screen.css  #all spaces everywhere
```

trying

```
sed -i 's/{ }//g' screen.css  #all spaces between brackets everywhere
```

does not work.

Can someone point me in the right direction.
(This command is running from a file/bash script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sed with regex ranges:

```
sed -i '/{/,/}/{s/\s*//g}' screen.css
```